# Javascript await is only valid in async functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function to delete items once a popup returns true:

```
function deleteItems(selectedItems){
    if (selectedItems.length > 0) {
        $("#confirm-popup-modal").modal("show");
        $("#confirm-popup-modal").one('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
            if ($("#confirm-modal").val() == "true") {
                var form_data = selectedItems;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("Delete", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(form_data),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.Result == true) {
                            var deleteId = result.Output;
                            await CompletedJobsAccess(deleteId);
                            table.draw();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Inside the Ajax success is another function called CompletedJobsAccess that will keep looping every 3 seconds to check if a job deletion has been completed:

```
function CompletedJobsAccess(DeleteId){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        var loopInterval = setInterval(function() { 
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Verify", "CompletedJobsAccess", new {area="Base" })",
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(DeleteId),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(verifyResult) {
                    if (verifyResult.IS_COMPLETED == true && verifyResult.IS_PROCESSING == false) {
                        if (verifyResult.IS_SUCCESSFUL == true) {
                            console.log(verifyResult.OUTPUT);
                            $.each($.parseJSON(verifyResult.OUTPUT), function(index, value) {
                                if (value.Result == true) {
                                    toastr.success(value.Message);
                                }else{
                                    toastr.error(value.Message);
                                }
                            });
                            clearInterval(loopInterval);
                        } else {
                            toastr.error(verifyResult.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function(innerError) {
                    console.log(innerError);
                }
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

However, when I load the page, and call  deleteItems(selected);, this is the error I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the
> top level bodies of modules

I tried searching around but I can't find if it can work within an ajax success function.

EDIT:

Added async to the ajax success function but the table draw function doesn't run.

```
function deleteItems(selectedItems){
    if (selectedItems.length > 0) {
        $("#confirm-popup-modal").modal("show");
        $("#confirm-popup-modal").one('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
            if ($("#confirm-modal").val() == "true") {
                var form_data = selectedItems;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("Delete", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(form_data),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: async function (result) {
                        if (result.Result == true) {
                            var deleteId = result.Output;
                            console.log("table before");
                            await CompletedJobsAccess(deleteId);
                            console.log("table draw");
                            table.draw();
                        }
                        table.draw();
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Updated CompletedJobsAccess to resolve promises:

```
function CompletedJobsAccess(DeleteId){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        var loopInterval = setInterval(function() { 
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Verify", "CompletedJobsAccess", new {area="Base" })",
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(DeleteId),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(verifyResult) {
                    if (verifyResult.IS_COMPLETED == true && verifyResult.IS_PROCESSING == false) {
                        if (verifyResult.IS_SUCCESSFUL == true) {
                            console.log(verifyResult.OUTPUT);
                            $.each($.parseJSON(verifyResult.OUTPUT), function(index, value) {
                                if (value.Result == true) {
                                    toastr.success(value.Message);
                                }else{
                                    toastr.error(value.Message);
                                }
                            });
                            clearInterval(loopInterval);
                            return Promise.resolve();
                        } else {
                            toastr.error(verifyResult.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            return Promise.resolve();
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function(innerError) {
                    console.log(innerError);
                }
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the success function `async`

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3",
  method: "GET",
  success: async function(data) {
    console.log("first - now wait a second ...");
    await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 1000));
    console.log("second, data:",data);
  },
  error: function(innerError) {
    console.log(innerError);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcdez7pf/) (can't work on this site because of CORS)

Comment: I put async in the success function but it doesn't run the console log after. I updated the question with an Edit.

Comment: @JianYA you never resolve your promise inside `CompletedJobsAccess`

Comment: If you pick an existing (CORS enabled) site then AJAX will work from SO too. I just edited this answer accordingly.

Comment: How do I return a promise inside my function properly? I updated my question with another edit showing what I did.

Answer (score 1):

In `CompletedJobsAccess(DeleteId)` you return a promise. But the way you set it up it will *never* execute the `resolve` function. So your `await` will wait forever ...

You could place the line

```
resolve();
```

right after

```
clearInterval(loopInterval);
```

in your `CompletedJobsAccess` function to make it work.

**Do not** return yet another `Promise.resolve()` like you did in your edited code.

A resolve function for a promise is never returned but executed.

Comment: How do I return a promise inside my function properly? I updated my question with another edit showing what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding `async` before all the `function` keyword like `async function deleteItems(selectedItems){` and also `$("#confirm-popup-modal").one('hidden.bs.modal', async function (event) {` and it should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `await` in functions that don't use the `async` keyword. `await` isn't available in regular functions. To solve this, you can change all the functions using `await` to `async function` to make it into an asynchronous function.

And if you don't want want to go through every function to make it asynchronous, you can just put the entire code inside an asynchronous IIFE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).